# Oracle split table column delimited values to to rows

Tags: sql, string, oracle, csv, recursive-query

Need to help with following
select col1, col2, split(col3) from test;

Table values:

```
Col1 col2 col3
xxx  yyy  a,b,c
iii  jjj  1,2,3
```

col3 contains comma-delimited values.

looking to achieve the following result. Splitting Col3 values for same col1 and col2 vlaue.

```
col1 col2 split
xxx  yyy  a
xxx  yyy  b
xxx  yyy  c
iii  jjj  1
iii  jjj  2
iii  jjj  3
```

Any regex or pl/sql function idea to help with this.

Comment: The best option would be to correct your data model.  Multiple (delimited) values in a single column violates First Normal Form.

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a standard recursive query:

```
with cte (col1, col2, pos, split, rest) as (
    select col1, col2, 1,
        substr(col3 || ',', 1, instr(col3 || ',', ',') - 1), 
        substr(col3 || ',', instr(col3 || ',', ',') + 1)
    from mytable 
    union all
    select col1, col2, pos + 1,
        substr(rest, 1, instr(rest, ',') - 1),
        substr(rest, instr(rest, ',') + 1)
    from cte 
    where instr(rest, ',') > 0
)
select col1, col2, split, pos from cte order by col1, col2, pos
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5d5fa389b92645ccfe96b768b23ceee4)**:

```
COL1 | COL2 | SPLIT | POS
:--- | :--- | :---- | --:
iii  | jjj  | 1     |   1
iii  | jjj  | 2     |   2
iii  | jjj  | 3     |   3
xxx  | yyy  | a     |   1
xxx  | yyy  | b     |   2
xxx  | yyy  | c     |   3
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be using Regular Expressions in order to split by commas and count the comma-seperated portions for the column `col3` within a Hierarchical Query :

```
 SELECT col1, col2, REGEXP_SUBSTR(col3,'[^,]',1,level) AS split
   FROM t
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(col3,',') + 1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR col1 = col1;

COL1    COL2    SPLIT
iii     jjj     1
iii     jjj     2
iii     jjj     3
xxx     yyy     a
xxx     yyy     b
xxx     yyy     c
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b97b965f408eb930a798d6721142d30f)</kbd>